# Heroku Rails App says "Application Error"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

When I try to access a recently posted Rails app on Heroku, it gives me the following error:

```
Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

When I check 'heroku logs' I see the following:

```
2013-02-15T18:56:06+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=olivetalk.org fwd=76.168.74.9 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-02-15T18:56:07+00:00 heroku[run.3278]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
2013-02-15T18:56:08+00:00 heroku[run.3278]: Process exited with status 0
2013-02-15T18:56:08+00:00 heroku[run.3278]: State changed from up to complete
2013-02-15T18:56:15+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=olivetalk.org fwd=76.168.74.9 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-02-15T18:56:17+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=olivetalk.org fwd=76.168.74.9 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I can't figure out what could be wrong. Any advice?

**UPDATE:** Here is the error from the loggly addon:

```
2013-02-15T19:50:43.659Z,default,54.234.29.222,115 <13>1 2013-02-15T19:50:43+00:00 d.26e71b30-db64-4275-b420-db8e0213d871 app web.1 - -     from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-02-15T19:50:43.659Z,default,54.234.29.222,176 <13>1 2013-02-15T19:50:43+00:00 d.26e71b30-db64-4275-b420-db8e0213d871 app web.1 - -     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-02-15T19:50:43.659Z,default,54.234.29.222,179 <13>1 2013-02-15T19:50:43+00:00 d.26e71b30-db64-4275-b420-db8e0213d871 app web.1 - -     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-02-15T19:50:43.659Z,default,54.234.29.222,129 <13>1 2013-02-15T19:50:43+00:00 d.26e71b30-db64-4275-b420-db8e0213d871 app web.1 - -     from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2013-02-15T19:50:43.659Z,default,54.234.29.222,198 <13>1 2013-02-15T19:50:43+00:00 d.26e71b30-db64-4275-b420-db8e0213d871 app web.1 - -     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-02-15T19:50:43.66Z,default,54.234.29.222,177 <13>1 2013-02-15T19:50:43+00:00 d.26e71b30-db64-4275-b420-db8e0213d871 app web.1 - -  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
2013-02-15T19:50:43.66Z,default,54.234.29.222,182 <13>1 2013-02-15T19:50:43+00:00 d.26e71b30-db64-4275-b420-db8e0213d871 app web.1 - -  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2013-02-15T19:50:43.66Z,default,54.234.29.222,169 <13>1 2013-02-15T19:50:43+00:00 d.26e71b30-db64-4275-b420-db8e0213d871 app web.1 - -  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2013-02-15T19:50:43.66Z,default,54.234.29.222,176 <13>1 2013-02-15T19:50:43+00:00 d.26e71b30-db64-4275-b420-db8e0213d871 app web.1 - -  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-02-15T19:50:43.66Z,default,54.234.29.222,170 <13>1 2013-02-15T19:50:43+00:00 d.26e71b30-db64-4275-b420-db8e0213d871 app web.1 - -  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2013-02-15T19:50:43.66Z,default,54.234.29.222,118 <13>1 2013-02-15T19:50:43+00:00 d.26e71b30-db64-4275-b420-db8e0213d871 app web.1 - -  from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-02-15T19:50:43.661Z,default,54.234.29.222,188 <13>1 2013-02-15T19:50:43+00:00 d.26e71b30-db64-4275-b420-db8e0213d871 app web.1 - -     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2013-02-15T19:50:43.661Z,default,54.234.29.222,175 <13>1 2013-02-15T19:50:43+00:00 d.26e71b30-db64-4275-b420-db8e0213d871 app web.1 - -     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2013-02-15T19:50:43.661Z,default,54.234.29.222,197 <13>1 2013-02-15T19:50:43+00:00 d.26e71b30-db64-4275-b420-db8e0213d871 app web.1 - -     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-02-15T19:50:43.661Z,default,54.234.29.222,184 <13>1 2013-02-15T19:50:43+00:00 d.26e71b30-db64-4275-b420-db8e0213d871 app web.1 - -     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2013-02-15T19:50:43.661Z,default,54.234.29.222,171 <13>1 2013-02-15T19:50:43+00:00 d.26e71b30-db64-4275-b420-db8e0213d871 app web.1 - -     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
2013-02-15T19:50:43.662Z,default,54.234.29.222,118 <13>1 2013-02-15T19:50:43+00:00 d.26e71b30-db64-4275-b420-db8e0213d871 app web.1 - -     from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2013-02-15T19:50:43.662Z,default,54.234.29.222,119 <13>1 2013-02-15T19:50:43+00:00 d.26e71b30-db64-4275-b420-db8e0213d871 app web.1 - -     from script/rails:6:in `require'
2013-02-15T19:50:44.749Z,default,50.17.90.179,127 <40>1 2013-02-15T19:50:44+00:00 d.26e71b30-db64-4275-b420-db8e0213d871 heroku web.1 - - State changed from starting to crashed
2013-02-15T19:50:44.924Z,default,54.234.29.222,117 <40>1 2013-02-15T19:50:44+00:00 d.26e71b30-db64-4275-b420-db8e0213d871 heroku web.1 - - Process exited with status 1
```

Comment: H10 just means your app is crashing, there should be other indicators in the logs.

Comment: Have you added the loggly or logentries addons to your app? They'll give you more information than what is available with just the heroku logs command.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I installed loggly and posted the loggly logs above. I still don't understand what is wrong though. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the 'PG' gem to your Gemfile (or properly configured your database.yml)? Heroku apps will crash if the DB is not setup properly.

Comment: I created the database and entered all the credentials. Is there anyway to simply check the database connection? Thanks so much